# How do I import js libraries and use it inside template literals – node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

I’m relatively new to node developing. The problem I´m about to report may sound simple, but I’m having a real hard time on figuring out.

Macro scenario: I’m building an html interface inside an object that uses template literal to build the html.

The basic problem I’m having is to use imported libraries inside javascript tags inside template literals. For example:

Beginning of the object code:

```
const Inputmask = require('inputmask');
```

Middle of the code:

```
backendHTML = `
<input type="text" id="categories_number1" name="number1" />
<script>
Inputmask("9", { repeat: 10 }).mask("categories_number1");
</script>
`;
```

When I run my app, it returns me the following error message:

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object. (R:\projetos_remoto\empreendimentos\syncsystem\tecnologia\multiplatform\version1.0.0\source_code8\node_modules\inputmask\dist\inputmask.js:13:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object. (R:\projetos_remoto\empreendimentos\syncsystem\tecnologia\multiplatform\version1.0.0\source_code8\node_modules\inputmask\index.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)

And this king of problem happens on other occasions I try to import some library and use it inside template literals.

Anyone can point out what concept I’m missing or doing wrong?
Note: I’m not using JQuery in my libraries.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you import these libraries in the front end of your app too?

Comment: No. The idea would be not to import in the frontend and just import in my object class. Unless I can get it to work with webpack, which I´m also having dificulties. I also posted a question about it and got no solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971030/webpack-4-simple-js-function-not-working-after-bundled-files